# EF Code first, how to register same table name with different schema?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We are using Entity Framework, Code First and in our database we have several tables that have the same name but in different Schemas.

I have also put the models in two different namespaces.

How i can register these tables in my DbContext class?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Data.Schema1.Contact>().ToTable("Contact", "schema1");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Data.Schema2.Contact>().ToTable("Contact", "schema2");
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your classes must have different name or you must use separate context for every schema.

The reason for this is EDM model used internally. Even if you are using code-first it still creates EDM model on behind and it must follow all its restrictions and the way how POCO classes are matched to entities defined in CSDL model. Entities from EDM are and POCO classes are matched by class name (without namespaces). Because of that each class name mapped in the same context must be unique and different namespace doesn't make it different class name.

Comment: The issue is that if I put the classes in two different context classes, I no longer can join the two tables....

Is there any way to get around that? 
Context.Contacts.Include("Contacts2");

Where Contact2 is from a different Context.

Comment: No you cannot make cross context queries. So the only option for you is to use different names for your classes - it will also make your code much more readable when you have to work with both types in same methods.

Comment: If I use a different a different class name and include the two in the same context, EF gives me an error:

Comment: If I use a different class name and include the two in the same context, EF gives me an error that the two entities can not share the same table (even though i am passing the "Schema" names either through the Table attribute or by using the fluent API)

Comment: This is simply a flaw in EF, regardless of their reasons, the full namespace of the POCO should be mapped, not just the class name. I have a modular structure in my application, and I have two "Field" classes, which within each module is relevant, both map to expanded table names.

Comment: One would think that using `HasEntitySetName` should work. Any idea why it doesn't? The output is correct on both sides (custom DB schemas, custom EDM prefixes) so it's not a by-design EF issue. Really I think it's just the model builder being silly with CLR namespaces. We're forced to prefix all types in some namespaces by their own namespace name, which really defeats the point of using them to begin with.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka any change to this as of EF 6.1.3?