# Entity Framework Code First - two entities with same name but in different namespaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have a problem with db generation in following scenario:

1.cs Project entity in First.Entities namespace maped to First_Project table.

```
namespace First.Entities
{
    #region using section

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

    #endregion

    [Table("First_Project")]
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

2.cs Project entity in Second.Entities namespace maped to Second_Project table.

```
namespace Second.Entities
{
    #region using section

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

    #endregion

    [Table("Second_Project")]
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

3.cs DbContext file

```
namespace DataContext
{
    #region using section

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
    using First.Entities;
    using Second.Entities;

    #endregion

    public class MyEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<First.Entities.Project> FirstProjects { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Second.Entities.Project> SecondProjects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What error(s) do you get? What do you need help with?

Comment: It is not possible to create Database in such scenario. Error is:

Comment: The type 'Second.Entities.Project' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

Comment: How to fix my scenario. I don't want to rename Project clases. I want to have 2 Project classes but in different namespaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible. Class name (without namespace) for every mapped entity in single context type must be unique. The reason is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551961/413501).

You must use different class names. Btw. using different (more specific) class names also makes your code better readable and your types better usable.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible, when you use a different database schema for both entities.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<First.Entities.Project>().ToTable("Project", "First");
     modelBuilder.Entity<Second.Entities.Project>().ToTable("Project", "Second");
}
```

Comment: "I think" -- please post answers with confidence that you *know* what you're saying. Did you actually try this yourself? If not, please do.

Comment: I'm using EF 6.1.3 and it's not possible. EF is throwing runtime error.