# "Multiple object sets per type are not supported" error when trying to map data from two different tables to a single domain type

Tags: entity-framework, dns, dbcontext

I am new to Entity Framework and I trying to setup Code First with following table structure

**Table: Client**

```
1. ClientID int
2. Name varchar(200)
3. Company varchar(200)
```

**Table: ERPConnection**

```
1. ClientID int (foreign key to client)
2. Server varchar(100)
3. Username varchar(100)
```

**Table: ERPAdminConnection**

```
1. ClientID int (foreign key to client)
2. Server varchar(100)
3. Username varchar(100)
```

As you can see there is one to one relationship between client->erpconnection and client->erpadminconnection. (Note: I did not design the tables,but I have to use it as is)

as you can see I do not need two different types to denote erp and erpadmin.

so I want to create a context something like this

```
public class ClientContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Connection> ERPConnection { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Connection> ERPAdminConnection { get; set; }
    public ClientContext(string connectionString)
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

However, when I ran some sample code with this I got an error ***" Multiple object sets per type are not supported. "***

How do I setup my classes so the above DBContext can be used without having to define a new type for ERPAdminConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Internally, the database to entity mappings are one-to-one, and each entity must be matched to a class with a unique name.

*[EF Code first, how to register same table name with different schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547150/ef-code-first-how-to-register-same-table-name-with-different-schema/8551961#8551961)*

---

An option is to have a base class and two derived classes (which won't need much defined within them if they're otherwise identical) and use [TPC inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.6).